# How to differentiate between users with the same name in a check-list

Tags: user-behavior, input-fields

I'm building a form that will have users selecting people in their household from a "select all" input.

We want to differentiate people in the household who may have the same name.

[image]

Is there any best practice for achieving this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what information you have about each person, you can help the user differentiate between people with the same name.

The *"Nobody in the household"* option makes me think that the names belong to family members. If that's the case, show the **relation** of the different names. Like so -

- Sarah *(Mother)*
- Sarah *(Daughter)*

If that's not the case, try to add discernible information or facts in addition to the name. Like so -

- Sarah *(39 y/o, born in Pennsylvania, MIT alumnus)*
- Sarah *(16 y/o, born in Boston, student at St. Mary's High School)*

And if you are saying that there is absolutely no discernible information available, I would recommend rethinking the form as it isn't good UX to show this kind of data. In most cases, the user is going to consider this as a duplicate entry which would lead to incorrect data entry.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just using the age. Do you think it's best to add "y/o" or just leave it at (39)

Comment: I think, *(Age: 39)* would be best. Just the number would cause confusion

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is a questionnaire. To differentiate the people you will have to ask them beforehand for an identification. This could be a the year of birth, a nickname. You could ask for a nick only if a name occurs more than once.

In households (or any group of people) having multiple persons with the same name face this problem in every day communication. In a lot of cases it is solved with nicknames.

The absolute minimum you could do is to use always the same order of the names in your form and give them a number. But this is not the best solution since the number does not connect to the real world and the user would have to remember which number belongs to which person.